# How to launch my console app executable in an Azure-Function

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-functions

I have created an Azure-Function app on Azure Portal.

Under `D:\home\site\wwwroot`,I have a `MyApp` folder and within it an executable `My.App.exe`.

I also have in this folder a `run.ps1` powershell script and I simply want the powershell script to launch the exe app.

Also I have this function.json :

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "MyApp",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */6 * * * *",
      "runOnStartup": true
    }
  ]
}
```

What must I put in the run.ps1 file in order to call the exe app?

I tried `& ".\My.App.exe"` and it gives :

```
2017-02-24T15:15:47.204 Function started (Id=0f4b9b0b-a1f5-4812-9d93-c4017da5ac1c)
2017-02-24T15:15:51.562 & : The term '.\My.App.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
at run.ps1: line 1
+ &
+ _
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\My.App.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I also tried `".\My.App.exe"` and it gives :

```
2017-02-24T15:26:29.312 Function started (Id=dced4842-069b-43c6-a055-aa06a46286c4)
2017-02-24T15:26:29.499 .\My.App.exe
2017-02-24T15:26:29.499 Function completed (Success, Id=dced4842-069b-43c6-a055-aa06a46286c4)
```

but it's as the exe was never launched because the first line in it is a `Console.WriteLine` and the log is empty

What is the correct command to put in the Powershell file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the discussion in comments, one solution is to use an explicit path:

```
& 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\MyApp\My.App.exe'
```

Your Azure function files should always exist under 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\{yourfunctionname}\'

Comment: Thanks, tried it : `The term '.\MyApp\My.App.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
`

Comment: However this worked! `& "D:\home\site\wwwroot\MyApp\My.App.exe"` Wondering where the `.` is pointing at in this context...

Comment: You could do `write-host $pwd` in your script and then maybe see it in the logfile? I always thought it was D:\home\site\wwwroot\{yourfunction} when I played with this before: http://wragg.io/a-slack-slash-command-using-powershell-azure-functions/